# paypal checkout перестает работать если входить в систему через Socialite

Tags: laravel5, paypal

Всем привет!
Сделал paypal checkout и он нормально работает если в систему входить через login форму(стандартный auth)

Но если входить в систему через Socialite (тестирую с аккаунтами Facebook, Google ) то получаю ошибку :

> Credential not found for default user. Please make sure your
>   configuration/APIContext has credential information

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider_name)
{
    if ( $provider_name == 'facebook' ) { 
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->scopes([
            "publish_actions, manage_pages", "publish_pages"])->redirect();
    }
    return Socialite::driver($provider_name)->redirect();
}

public function handleSocialiteProviderCallback($provider_name)
{
    $settingsArray   = Settings::getSettingsList(['site_name']);
    $site_name       = !empty($settingsArray['site_name']) ? $settingsArray['site_name'] : '';
    $site_home_url   = \URL::to('/');

    $provider_name= (string)$provider_name;
    $is_debug= true;
    try {

        $socialiteUser = Socialite::driver($provider_name)->user();

        $loggedUser = User::where('provider_id', $socialiteUser->id)->first();

        if ($loggedUser !== null ) { // There is already user is system - just login under it's credentials
            Auth::login($loggedUser, true);
            \Event::dispatch(new backendSuccessOnLoginEvent($loggedUser));
            return redirect()->route('home');
        } // if ($loggedUser) { // There is already user is system - just login under it's credentials
...
```

И в модуле оплаты app/Paypal/ExecutePayment.php :

```
<?php
namespace App\Paypal;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;

class ExecutePayment extends PaypalConnection
{
    use funcsTrait;
    private $payment;
    public function create() {

        $is_debug= false;
        if ($is_debug) {
            echo '<pre>paymentId::' . print_r(request('paymentId'), true) . '</pre>';
        }

        $loggedUser= Auth::user();
        $this->debToFile(print_r( ( !empty($loggedUser->id) ? $loggedUser->id : '') , true), ' GetThePayment  -0SA $loggedUser->id::');

        $this->payment = $this->GetThePayment();
```

$this->debToFile - это вывод в отладочный файл и он отображает что $loggedUser->id == null

И файл выше наследуется от app/Paypal/PaypalConnection.php :

```
<?php


namespace App\Paypal;

use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;
use Auth;


class PaypalConnection
{
    use funcsTrait;

    protected $apiContext;
    private $loggedUser;

    public function __construct($loggedUser)
    {

        if ( !Auth::check() ) {
            return redirect()->route('home-msg', [])->with([
                'text'   => 'You need to login into the system !',
                'type'   => 'danger',
                'action' => 'show-login'
            ]);
        }
        $this->loggedUser= $loggedUser;
        $this->debToFile(print_r($this->loggedUser->id, true), ' PaypalConnection  -0A $this->loggedUser->id::');// ЭТА СТРОКА ВЫВОДИТ ТЕКУЩИЙ  $this->loggedUser->id


        $this->debToFile(print_r(config('services.paypal'), true), " PaypalConnection  -0A config('services.paypal.id')::"); // ВЫВОДИТ ПРАВИЛЬНЫЕ ПАРАМЕТРЫ  PAYPAL-конфигурации

        $this->apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
            new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
                config('services.paypal.id'),
                config('services.paypal.secret')
            )
        );

        // ПОХОЖЕ СТРОКА ВЫШЕ КАКИМ-ТО ОБРАЗОМ ВЫПОЛНЯЕТ ЛОГ ОУТ ТЕКУЩЕГО ЮЗЕРА - после ручного возврата в программу и вижу что был выполнен логаут

    }
}
```

ExecutePayment - вызывается из контролла app/Http/Controllers/PaymentController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

use App\Settings;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use App\library\CheckValueType;
use App\Paypal\CreatePayment;
use App\Paypal\ExecutePayment;
use App\Paypal\SubscriptionPlan;
use App\Payment;
use App\PaymentItem;

use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;


class PaymentController extends MyAppController
{
    use funcsTrait;


    private $loggedUser;
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function paypal_payment()
    {
        $request     = request();
        $requestData = $request->all();

        $this->loggedUser = Auth::user();

        if ( empty($this->loggedUser->first_name) or
             empty($this->loggedUser->last_name or
             empty($this->loggedUser->address_line1) or
             empty($this->loggedUser->address_city) or
             empty($this->loggedUser->address_state) or
             empty($this->loggedUser->address_postal_code) or
             empty($this->loggedUser->address_country_code) or
             empty($this->loggedUser->shipping_address_line1) or
             empty($this->loggedUser->shipping_address_city) or
             empty($this->loggedUser->shipping_address_state) or
             empty($this->loggedUser->shipping_address_postal_code) or
             empty($this->loggedUser->shipping_address_country_code)
             ) ) {

            return redirect()->route('home-msg', [])->with([
                'text'   => 'To make payment fill your profile, including First name, Last name, Address, Shipping address !',
                'type'   => 'danger',
                'action' => 'show-profile'
            ]);
        }
        $this->loggedUser = Auth::user();

        $payment= new CreatePayment($this->loggedUser);
        return $payment->Create($requestData);

    }

    public function paypal_payment_execute()
    {
        echo '<pre>paypal_payment_execute::' . print_r(-1, true) . '</pre>';
        $this->loggedUser = Auth::user();

        $this->debToFile(print_r( ( !empty($this->loggedUser->id) ? $this->loggedUser->id : '' ), true) , ' paypal_payment_execute  -000 $this->loggedUser->id::');

        $newPayment= new ExecutePayment($this->loggedUser);
        try {
        $newPaymentResult= $newPayment->create();
        } catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $pce) {
            echo '<pre>Error Block # 1</pre>';
            var_dump("-1:" . json_decode($pce->getData()));
            exit(1);
        } catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $pce) {
            echo '<pre>Error Block # 2</pre>';
            var_dump("-2:" . json_decode($pce->getData()));
            exit(1);
        } catch (Exception $pce) {
            echo '<pre>Error Block # 3</pre>';
            var_dump("-3:" . json_decode($pce->getData()));
            exit(1);

        }

        if ( $newPaymentResult->state != 'approved' ) { // payment was successful
            return redirect()->route('home-msg', [])->with([
                'text'   => 'Your payment was successfully completed !',
                'type'   => 'danger',
                'action' => ''
            ]);
        }

        $newAppayment= new \App\Payment();
        $newAppayment->user_id= $this->loggedUser->id;
        $newAppayment->status= 'C';
        $newAppayment->payment_type= 'P';
        $newAppayment->payment_status= $newPaymentResult->state;
        $newAppayment->payment_description= $newPaymentResult->transactions[0]->description;
        $newAppayment->invoice_number= $newPaymentResult->transactions[0]->invoice_number;

        $newAppayment->payer_id= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->payer_id;
        $newAppayment->payer_recipient_name= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->recipient_name;

        $newAppayment->payer_email= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->email;
        $newAppayment->payer_first_name= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->first_name;
        $newAppayment->payer_last_name= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->last_name;
        $newAppayment->payer_middle_name= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->middle_name;

        $newAppayment->currency= $newPaymentResult->transactions[0]->amount->currency;
        $newAppayment->total= $newPaymentResult->transactions[0]->amount->total;
        $newAppayment->subtotal= $newPaymentResult->transactions[0]->amount->details->subtotal;
        $newAppayment->tax= $newPaymentResult->transactions[0]->amount->details->tax;
        $newAppayment->shipping= $newPaymentResult->transactions[0]->amount->details->shipping;


        $newAppayment->payer_shipping_address= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->shipping_address->line1;
        $newAppayment->payer_recipient_name= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->shipping_address->recipient_name;
        $newAppayment->payer_city= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->shipping_address->city;
        $newAppayment->payer_state= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->shipping_address->state;
        $newAppayment->payer_postal_code= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->shipping_address->postal_code;
        $newAppayment->payer_country_code= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->shipping_address->country_code;
        $newAppayment->payer_business_name= $newPaymentResult->payer->payer_info->business_name;

        $itemsList= $newPaymentResult->transactions[0]->item_list;

        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $newAppayment->save();

            foreach( $itemsList->items as $next_key=>$nextItem ) {
                $newPaymentItem= new PaymentItem();
                $newPaymentItem->payment_id= $newAppayment->id;
                $newPaymentItem->item_type= 'D';
                $newPaymentItem->quantity= $nextItem->quantity;
                $newPaymentItem->item_id= $nextItem->sku;
                $newPaymentItem->price= $nextItem->price;
                $newPaymentItem->save();
        }

            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            $this->setFlashMessage($e->getMessage(), 'danger');

            echo '<pre>$e->getMessage()::'.print_r($e->getMessage(),true).'</pre>';
            die("-1 EOOR");
            return Redirect
                ::back()
                ->withErrors([$e->getMessage()])
                ;
        }
        return redirect()->route('home-msg', [])->with([
            'text'   => 'Your payment was successfully completed !',
            'type'   => 'success',
            'action' => ''
        ]);

    }

    public function paypal_payment_cancel()
    {
        echo '<pre>paypal_payment_cancel::' . print_r(-1, true) . '</pre>';
        die("-1 XXZ paypal_payment_cancel app/Http/Controllers/PaymentController.php");
    }


}
```

Как я писал в начале если войти в систему через login форму(стандартный auth) - ошибки нет.

Почему ошибка и как ее исправить ?

при логине в handleSocialiteProviderCallback я использовал

```
// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::login($user, true);
```

Или вызова этой функции недостаточно ?

Следующая мысль это проверить 2х юзеров по полям : https://prnt.sc/p10ry9
Для юзера созданного в facebook(id=42) поле password было пустым - я его скопировал из id=6 - 
залогинился из facebook-а заново - но та же ошибка.
остальные поля : https://prnt.sc/p10tc9, https://prnt.sc/p10tok, https://prnt.sc/p10tsh
Я заполнил address, shipping_address поля при логине юзера из facebook-а. Если эти поля пустые - то выводит paypal ошибку.
я там сделал проверку.
То есть вроде все поля заполнены одинаково - и каким образом и почему теряется логин - непонятно...

**ПРАВКА #1 :**

Кажется нашел причину в том что у меня в приложении были переходы

```
https://mysite.com
https://www.mysite.com
```

и в .htaccess я писал :

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

в .env :

```
APP_URL=https://mysite.com
```

И при текущем урле с “www.” на урл без него текущий юзер терялся ... такое возможно?
И вообще нужны ли “www.” в урле сайта ?

Спасибо !

Comment: Приатачу принтскрин с ошибкой   https://prnt.sc/p1o9tn
Идей никаких ?

Comment: Я нашел причину ошибки в ПРАВКА #1 :